# Configure Oracle 23c docker image in 19c compatibility mode

Tags: oracle, docker

I need to build an Oracle 19c development environment using Docker; however there is no dev version of Oracle 19c with Partitioning available, whereas 23c does have a free version for developers with partitioning.

I have downloaded the free docker image from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/free/get-started/), but I recently found that you can't reduce the compatibility level (using `ALTER SYSTEM SET COMPATIBLE = '19.0.0' SCOPE=SPFILE;`) once the db is created.

Without creating my own custom image, is it possible to set the compatible to 19 for the database, using docker-compose?

docker-compose section:

```yml
db:
        image: mydocker/myrepo:oracle23free
        restart: always
        environment:
                - ORACLE_PWD=securepassword
        ports:
                - "1521:1521"
                - "5500:5500"
        volumes:
                - ./dbscripts/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/startup
```

currently I have a script to set the compatibility mode here, but it doesn't work (the database won't start up) - I see the following in the logs after rebooting the database:

> ORA-00201: control file version 23.0.0.0.0 incompatible with ORACLE version 19.0.0.0.0

> ORA-00202: control file: '/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/control01.ctl'

(see also https://serverfault.com/questions/1143690/restarting-oracle-23c-within-the-docker-container-causes-blocked-listener, when I didn't know why the db wouldn't start up)

Comment: Short answer: NO.

Comment: well that was very short, thank you for that!!

Comment: My understanding is that you could set it at the point of installation of the database. Is that true? The docker `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder has a `setup` folder as well as a `startup` one. So couldn't you add a script or something to the `setup` folder to set the `compatibility` parameter there?

Answer (score 1):

OK then, long answer:

`compatible` is specified when a database is created from scratch. It can be set to a higher value after upgrading the database to a newer version. **It can not be lowered.**

Oracle 23c Free comes with a pre-built database with `compatible` set to `23.0.0`.